# Выполнение отложенной задачи

Tags: php, ispmanager

Как правильно сделать отложенную отправку запроса url
Задача:
Нужно сделать отложенный постинг сообщений, пользователь пишет сообщение, выбирает дату публикации
Создается запись в БД, нужно обратиться к url в заданное время
Например site.ru/post/create/35 - в 15:00

Будет более 100 000 отложенных сообщений в день

Через что правильно делать такую задача?
Подойдет ли cron для большого кол-ва задач?

Comment: Изменить подход к задаче? зачем нужен отложенный запрос? почему не создать запись заранее и просто не отображать ее до наступления момента X?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Нужно для отложенного постинга сообщений в группе вконтакте. Пользователь заходит на сайт, добавляет свою свою группу и настраивает отложенный постинг для своей группы

Comment: Должно помочь google -> cron

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Спасибо. Извиняюсь, перепутал в вопросе, вместо job хотел написать cron. С cron работал, но в маленьком объеме, 1 запрос в неделю. Как cron работает с большим объемом запросов?

Comment: Что значит большой объем :) никогда не пытался запускать кроном тысячи задач, зато по задаче в минуту - вполне себе способ: Раз в минуту запускается скрипт который "достает" из базы все задачи время исполнения которых подошло, и например с помощью curl(multi curl в вашем случае) - делает все необходимые запросы( в вашем случае лучше пачками если на каждое сообщение нужен отдельный запрос) https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php